# SE and CI not aligning in R output from RVE meta-regression (robumeta)

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, standard-error, meta-analysis

I implemented a random-variance-estimation meta-analysis in R using the robumeta command. I am puzzled by the R output in terms of interpreting the significance level. I am copying an example of the output below. According to standard error and t-value, the effect should be significant at the 5% level, however, according to the 95% CI and the indicated significance level, the effect is only significant at the 10% level. I wonder which information is correct and why there is this discrepancy?

[image: R Output:]

Comment: What makes you say that a t of 2.08 with  5.65 df should be significant? I tested it in R and got a sig. level of 0.06.

Comment: Thank you!  I always thought that the rule of thumb is: if x SE is < than the coefficient, an effect is s significant at the 5% level. But then this rule doesn't always apply?

Comment: The critical value for your t-statistic is `qt(.975, df=5.65)` or about 2.484 in this case. The printout even conveniently provides the *P*-value, which is decidedly > 0.05.